# Postfix: fail2ban and iptables bans don't stop connections and authentication attempts

Tags: postfix, fail2ban

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with Postfix 3.1.0 and fail2ban 0.9.3. Nowadays my `/var/log/mail.log` is constantly polluted with bruteforce attempts like this:

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[2282]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
postfix/submission/smtpd[2282]: warning: unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
postfix/submission/smtpd[2282]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
```

I tried to set up `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` as:

```
[postfix]
enabled  = true
port     = smtp,ssmtp
filter   = postfix
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 3
bantime = 86400

[sasl]
enabled  = true
port     = smtp,ssmtp,imap2,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s
filter   = postfix-sasl
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 3
bantime = 86400
```

It seems to be working properly according to `/var/log/fail2ban.log`:

```
fail2ban.filter   [2208]: INFO    [sasl] Found xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
fail2ban.actions  [2208]: NOTICE  [sasl] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx already banned
```

But smtpd keeps receiving SASL authentication attempts.

I also tried `iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP` the other day but connects and authentication attempts continue despite the explicit `DROP` (`iptables -L INPUT -v -n`):

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  416 2974K f2b-sasl   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,143,220,993,110,995
 1763  170K f2b-wordpress-soft  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
 1763  170K f2b-wordpress-hard  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
  416 2974K f2b-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465
 1891  144K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
33899 8794K ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
33899 8794K ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  136  6931 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  113  5875 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  113  5875 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  113  5875 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Try, port config, renaming `ssmtp` to `smtps` or `465` and adding `submission` port or `587` and restart. Also for jail action you'll need `smpts` and `submission` somtehing like this `iptables-multiport[name=postfix-sasl, port="smtp,smtps,submission", protocol=tcp]`

Answer (score 2):

Try, port config, renaming `ssmtp` to `smtps` or `465` and adding `submission` port or `587` and restart.

Also for jail action you'll need `smpts` and `submission` ports

Similar to this one

```
iptables-multiport[name=postfix-sasl, port="smtp,smtps,submission", protocol=tcp]
```

Comment: Unfortunately you were too presumptive in what we might do to follow your advice. Are you asking us to edit /etc/services to change these definitions, or something else? And, please clarify what you mean when you say you want us to add submission port or 587 - WHERE, exactly, please? (By the way, I'm using systemd with firewalld, the modern Fedora Core way, if that matters)

Comment: Richard T, the changes indicated above have to be done on the jail definition in jail.local, exactly where jail definition explicit where to insert iptables rules - as above. After that, check with fail2ban-regex (fail2ban-regex --usage) and reload the daemon with "systemctl restart fail2ban" or "fail2ban-client reload", both works.